# How to Write into multiple files with Spring Batch using writer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How to Write into multiple files with Spring Batch using writer, Multiple files depends on data return from Database. Any better solution to implement in Spring Batch

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html)

> Calls one of a collection of ItemWriters for each item, based on a router pattern implemented through the provided Classifier.